# Question about divergences of functions Vs divergences of their expansions

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

I have the following function
$$f(a,x)=\frac{1}{(1-a\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$
For small x (i.e. $x<<1$), I can Taylor expand around $x=0$, according to
$$f(a,x)=\frac{1}{1-a}-\frac{ax^2}{2(1-a)^2}+\mathcal{O}(x^4)$$
Now, for $a=1$, the first expression reduces to
$$f(a=1,x)=\frac{1}{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$
which does not diverge if $x$ is small, but finite, correct? Why does the Taylor expanded version diverge, then, for $a=1$, but for $x$ finite and small?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as $x \to 0$, $f(1,x) \to \infty$ (the denominator goes to $0$) and $f(1,0)$ does not exist at all.  For a Taylor series around $x=0$ to exist at all, you need the function and all its derivatives to be defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! However, one last question: if $x$ is small, but finite, the denominator of the (non Taylor expanded) $f(x)$ does not blow for $a=1$, instead, it is well-defined. However, expanding around $x=0$ causes this ill-defined behavior for the Taylor expanded version of $f(x)$. Am I for some reason not allowed to Taylor expand?? This is my confusion... Because the expanded and non-expanded versions give contradictions

Comment: There's no contradiction. By definition, the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x = a$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k$$
Thus it can only exist if $f$ and all its derivatives exist at $x = a$. There may be other series that exist, but they are not Taylor series around $x=a$.

Comment: In the case at hand ($1/(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})$ around $x=0$), there is a Laurent series expansion
$$ \frac{2}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2}  - \frac{x^2}{8} - \frac{x^4}{16} - \frac{5 x^6}{128} - \ldots $$
but it's not a Taylor series.

Comment: And $x$ can be finite, but small in the Laurent series, correct? And depending on the validity of my approximation, I can neglect to some extend higher order terms, yes?